# How to merge vertices of a ripped model?

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify

[image: This, for example]

After I spent like 2 hours rigging a model with riggify I've realized the model I've ripped the other day has the articulations unmerged (shoulders, knees, etc), after moving one arm.

Is it possible to merge all the holes without going arm by arm, knee by knee, and making sure all is properly merge?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved using "remove doubles".
Thanks anyway.